# Why am I getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to tokenize the input from the console (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, delimiter, tokenize

I'm trying to separate the input from the console using the split method, and then putting each of these values into separate containers, and I keep on getting this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1`. I assume the issue is that it ignores the input after the first space, but I am clueless as to why and how to solve that.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and advise what I should do so that the text after the space is stored in my container? Thank you in advance.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input the name and phone no: ");
    String text = s.next();

    String[] temp = text.split(" ");

    String name = temp[0];
    String phoneNoTemp = temp[1];

    System.out.println(name + ": name");
    System.out.println(phoneNoTemp + ": phoneNoTemp");
```

The input I tried it with was:

```
Input the name and phone no: 
kate 99912222
```

Sidenote: Yes, I did import the scanner

Comment: Scanner's next method will take only first part of the string . If there is space in between the string it will not pick up the second part , hence you are getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `s.nextLine()` instead of `s.next()` because the `next()` method only consumes until the next delimiter, which defaults to any whitespace.